# Trying to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreSaveInstanceState in order to save my activity state but it does not work

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a quiz app so that when the user clicks the plus button it takes them to a page where they input the question and answer which they can then save and is taken back to the previous page where a new button with the text set to the question is created. I have all of this coded and working except for the part where I can save the question/answer activity state if the user wants to edit it. I've tried to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreSaveInstanceState but it didn't save the activity at all. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

Main Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
        }
    }
}}
```

Second Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener{
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        Log.i("Instance State", "onSaveInstanceState")

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        outState.putCharSequence("savedQuestion", question.toString())
        outState.putCharSequence("savedAnswer", answer.toString())
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        Log.i("Restored Instance State", "onRestoreInstanceState")

        val question = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedQuestion")
        val answer = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedAnswer")

        val txt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val txt2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        txt.setText(question)
        txt2.setText(answer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the use case for `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. You should use them when your Activity is recreated. For example: device is rotated.

In your case, you are starting a new instance of `SecondActivity` when you are starting it from `MainActivity`.

To achieve what you want, you should pass the question and answer from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity` using a `Bundle` and then let the user edit them.

Comment: im not sure how i would the two edit texts into a bundle from the main activity if they are located in my second activity.

Comment: How exactly would i do this?